# Stop only if some key is pressed in C

Tags: c, macos, keyboard, while-loop

If I had a while loop that I wanted to stop only if the q key is pressed how would I do that.
However, I do NOT want it to quite the program

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int boolean;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
char *script = malloc(MAXPATH);
script = "ls";
boolean a;
a = TRUE;
while(a){ //this is the while loop i want to break incase of a keypress
system(script);
}

do something else 
something else....
```

This will be running on Mac OS X.

both getchar() and getc() pause for a response which makes loop stop

Comment: On which platform?  This question cannot be answered in the abstract.

Comment: Which platform?  There is no answer that is not platform specific.  There is no answer provided by the Standard C library.

Comment: Mac os x. Running 10.7.3 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

native functions in C with which i can detect a keypress are :

```
 getchar() and getc()

 kbhit() is a function returns integer value whenever the key is pressed
```

you can use the above functions

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <time.h>

  int main()
  {
  int m;
  clrscr();
  do
    {

   if(kbhit())
     {
     if((m=getch())==97)
       {
        printf("Key a is pressed....\n");
       }
      }
 }  while(1);
    getch();
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `getchar()` and `getc()` are blocking calls. And `kbhit()` is not part of ANSI C standards. Its just a feature provided by Borland compilers

Answer (score 2):

you can use select() mechanism in UNIX-LIKE OS.

all in one function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int ch;
    int bool, ret;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    bool = 1;
    while (bool) {
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds);
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        /* int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
         *           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);         */
        ret = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("select error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            /* timeout */
        } else if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds)) {
            ch = fgetc(stdin);
            if (ch == 'q') {
                bool = 0;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer poll() over select() in almost all cases. And prefer kqueue/epoll on OSX/Linux over poll() when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad of alexchandel's answer. I had never heard of poll()

poll() is a good answer for POSIX style systems like the questioner's platform

_kbhit() is the simplest answer on MS Windows. Their Poll() is different of course

The 1 means just one descriptor block in my list, the 100 is milliseconds timout

my file handle is { 0,  for stdin

read the man page for the many events you can interrogate, I only wanted POLLIN

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <errno.h>

static struct pollfd attention = { 0, POLLIN } ;

int main()
{
   int   x, y;

   for (;;)
   {
      x = poll(&attention, 1, 100);

      if (x < 0)
      {
         printf("problem %d\n", errno);
         break;
      }
      else if (x)
      {
         printf("you rang %x ?", x);
         y = getc(stdin);
         printf(" %c of course\n", y);
         if (y == '.') break;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the computation run in a pthread while the main loop reads char on stdin. SDL library has better input controls if you don't just want to read char from stdin. gtk also has events that the window receives. The command "xev" is a xlib program for linux that works similarly. It opens a blank window and it reads key events as they come.